# how to regenerate rss feed by facebook page/user url using java?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

i want to know how to regenerate rss feed by facebook's page url using java. for instance, when i input an url, such as :

> https://www.facebook.com/MiraiProject/

then the result would be a rss feed of that page, such as :

> https://www.facebook.com/123065781135648_1329441560498058

is it possible to do that? if possible how i could do that? thanks!

Comment: If you separate this into the two questions, “how do I get the posts from a Facebook page”, and “how do I create an RSS feed from given data”, you should be able to find plenty information to get started.

Comment: i know how to get the post and rss from our own facebook page using OAuth stuff, but dunno how to get from other facebook page.

Comment: Well if the page is public and the posts are not targeted to specific users, then you can just use your app access token. A page token is out of the question, if you don't have admin access to the page. As a last resort, you could use your own user access token, to get all posts your account can see - but then you should be careful, as to not expose posts to audiences how could otherwise not see them ...

Comment: hmm, before we are going too far to nowhere, simply i want make function just like this website do http://fetchrss.com/ but in jsf.